# Collision over drawings

Tags: probability

I have a set $X$ of $2^{56}$ distinct items from which I randomly draw a set $A$ of $2^{24}$ items (without replacement).  I then return all the items from $A$ to restore $X$.  Now I randomly draw a second set, $B$, of $2^{24}$ items from $X$ (without replacement).  What is the expected number of items that appeared in both $A$ and $B$?

Comment: With "number of collisions" do you mean the cardinality of $A\cap B$ (as a random variable)?

Comment: Yes, David has edited my question and clarified that point.

Answer (score 1):

Number the items $1,2,\dots,2^{56}$.

Let $X_i$ take value $1$ if item $i$ is in set $A$ and value $0$ otherwise.

Let $Y_i$ take value $1$ if item $i$ is in set $B$ and value $0$ otherwise.

Then $Z:=\sum_{i=1}^{2^{56}}X_iY_i$ is the cardinality of $A\cap B$ and with linearity of expectation and symmetry we find:$$\mathbb EZ=\mathbb E\sum_{i=1}^{2^{56}}X_iY_i=\sum_{i=1}^{2^{56}}\mathbb EX_iY_i=2^{56}\mathbb EX_1Y_1=2^{56}P(X_1=1,Y_1=1)=2^{56}P(X_1=1)P(Y_1=1)=$$$$2^{56}\frac{2^{24}}{2^{56}}\frac{2^{24}}{2^{56}}=2^{-8}=\frac1{256}$$

The fifth equality rests on independence.

---

P.S. Whenever you are asked to find an *expectation* then check out whether this method (or something like it) can be used and wrestling with distribution can be avoided. It gives you insight and spares you a lot of time.

Quite often you do not actually need the (eventually complex) distribution if you must calculate an expectation.

Comment: Thank for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is described by the [Hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution), and for your numbers the mean number of collisions is $1/256$.  That is, the chance is extremely low that you'll even get one "collision."

Here's a plot of the probability of getting $n$ collisions for $|A| = |B| = 2^{12}$ and $|X| = 2^{16}$.

[image]

Comment: Thank for your answer David.

Comment: @MoonVincent:  But not even an upvote?

Answer (score 0):

I had an idea for approach that is probably reinventing the wheel, but it comes from basic principles.

First, figure out how many ways there are to make your selections so that A and B share no common elements. Then figure out how many ways there are to select where they have only one common element, and so on. Add them up then divide by the total number of ways of making your selection.

0 items : $C(2^{56},2^{24})*C(2^{56}-2^{24},2^{24})$

1 item: $C(2^{56},1)*C(2^{56}-1,2^{24}-1)*C(2^{56}-2^{24},2^{24}-1)$

2 items: $C(2^{56},2)*C(2^{56}-2,2^{24}-2)*C(2^{56}-2^{24},2^{24}-2)$

So numerator = $\sum_{i=0}^{2^{24}}C(2^{56},i)*C(2^{56}-i,2^{24}-i)*C(2^{56}-2^{24},2^{24}-i)$

Denominator = $C(2^{56},2^{24})^2.$

Factor of half there to prevent over counting.

Where C(A,B) is the binomial coefficient = $\frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}$

Throw in the Stirling Approximation: $C(n,k)\approx\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi k}(\frac{ne}
{k})^k}$

That should get you something workable.

Gut tells me you'll have to divide by two to account for over counting. But I drawing a blank as to why.

Comment: Thank for your answer.